# Copy and paste a formula using VBA:returning a #REF! instead of referenced cell

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am reasonably new to VBA... I have built a report and macro but am stuck copy and pasting a formula from one sheet to another.

This is the part of the code I am having problems with...

```
Worksheets("Data Checks").Range("B11").Copy Worksheets("Items By Location").Range("Y2")
```

So Id like to copy the following formula from `Worksheets("Data Checks").Range("B11")` to `Worksheets("Items By Location").Range("Y2")`

The formula is as follows...

```
=OR(LEFT('Items By Location'!D2, 4)="JV05", LEFT('Items By Location'!D2, 4)="JVAW",  LEFT('Items By Location'!D2, 5)="HARHW")
```

But when the macro runs it pastes as...

```
=OR(LEFT('Items By Location'!#REF!, 4)="JV05", LEFT('Items By Location'!#REF!, 4)="JVAW",  LEFT('Items By Location'!#REF!, 5)="HARHW")
```

I need it to keep the 'D2' which will then be auto filled down to the bottom of the report.

I know it may be easier to type out the formula but I'd like this formula to be amendable without going into VBA.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated

Many thanks
Harvey

Comment: That second line doesn't work and doesn't do what you're trying to do, you can simply delete the line.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying various lines of code and left that one in there by mistake. I still have the same issue just using that first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you copy the cell, the formula will adjust since it's a relative reference. To avoid that, assign the formula string directly from one to the other:

```
Worksheets("Items By Location").Range("Y2").Formula = Worksheets("Data Checks").Range("B11").Formula
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you're trying to achieve:

```
Worksheets("Items By Location").Range("Y2").Formula = Worksheets("Data Checks").Range("B11").Formula
```

This will also be a bit more efficient.

Comment: Glad to help, please consider accepting an answer to close the question and make it easier to find for other users.